# ios 8.3 custom url scheme not working

Tags: ios, ios8, ios8.3

I implemented my app with custom url scheme to access it. When I scan QR image which has custom url , app will be opened . Till ios 7 worked fine , but it is not working in ios 8.3 , even when i manually enter custom url scheme in safari browser. I have a doubt that still ios support custom url scheme ?

this is the method, to receive url scheme input, here i pass input to my viewController. urlScheme is `myapp://settings?name:xxx?age=24`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    if (!url) { return NO; }
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url];
    NSLog(@"inside openURL %@",urlString);
    HomeViewController *vc = [[HomeViewController alloc]init];
    vc.isURLLaunch = 1;
    vc.urlData = urlString;
    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:vc];
    [navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];

    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: I am using custom URL schemes in iOS 8 without problems. Without code we can't help you! Pots your code!

Comment: Maybe this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29970918/ios-return-to-safari-from-native-app-without-opening-new-tab/30429912#30429912

Comment: Hi, thanks for  your reply,I edited my question with my source code , my QR image will have url ( myapp://settings?name:xxx?age=24 )

Comment: Have you declared the custom url in the build target? Please see the link I provided to verify this.

Comment: yeah , I added, even it works fine for <=ios 7

Comment: Take a screenshot on how you added the custom url to the target and post it here

Comment: sorry for the late reply dude @JuanCatalan , I couldnt post image , since i dont have 10 reputation