# Go back to previous app(Swift ios)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

My application can open PDF-files. So I registered it for PDF-files. When I open a PDF-file from the mail-app my application get called and the following function is called:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        let rect = app.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.view.bounds
        viewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        let picker = UIPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: (rect?.width)!, height: (rect?.height)! / 3))
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.dataSource = self
        viewController.view.addSubview(picker)
        let okButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 100 + ((rect?.height)! / 3), width: ((rect?.width)! / 2) - 20, height: 30))
        okButton.setTitle("Ok", for: .normal)
        okButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(AppDelegate.endApp), for: .touchUpInside)
        viewController.view.addSubview(okButton)
        app.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        return true
    }
```

This works! If the user click on the ok Button I want to go back to the mail-app. How can I do this? I read, that apple don't allow you to switch between apps. But whatsApp is doing this.

I tried it with removing the viewController:

```
viewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
```

But then I only get a black screen.

Comment: This will not help you to go back to mail app viewController.view.removeFromSuperview()

Comment: this dont help me as much as your answer :). Do you have a solution for this problem?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I made it with the following code:

```
viewController.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)   
let mailURL = NSURL(string: "message://")!
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(mailURL as URL) {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(mailURL as URL)
        }
```

Thats good enough for me.

thank you @Jeremy your link helped me!

Answer (score 1):

The only way to launch other applications is by using their URL schemes, the only way to open mail is by using the mailto: scheme, which will always open the compose view.

```
let email = "foo@bar.com"

let url = URL(string: "mailto:\(email)")
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
```

Edit: this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30429912/2106940) might help you

Comment: Well but how is Whatsapp doing it?

Answer (score -1):

This will not help you to go back to mail app `viewController.view.removeFromSuperview()`

It will just remove views from your viewcontroler and black color `window` is showing.

There is no way to get back to mail-app even if you use openURL.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"mailto:"]];
```

This will open email composer, but practically you will not be able to get back to mail app.

**Swift**

```
let url = URL(string: "mailto:\abc@xyz.com")
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
```

This will open email composer with sender as abc@xyz.com.

If you want to attach file and send it through email composer, then make like below code.

import UIKit
    import MessageUI

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

@IBAction func launchEmail(sender: AnyObject) {

var emailTitle = "EmailTitle"
var messageBody = "Email BodyFeature request or bug report?"
var toRecipents = ["abc@xyz.com"]
var mc: MFMailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()
mc.mailComposeDelegate = self
mc.setSubject(emailTitle)
mc.setMessageBody(messageBody, isHTML: false)
mc.setToRecipients(toRecipents)

self.presentViewController(mc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func mailComposeController(controller:MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result:MFMailComposeResult, error:NSError) {
    switch result {
    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
        print("Mail cancelled")
    case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
        print("Mail saved")
    case MFMailComposeResultSent:
        print("Mail sent")
    case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
        print("Mail sent failure: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
    default:
        break
    }
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

}
```

Comment: Well but how is Whatsapp doing it?

Comment: That opens email composer only. doesnt redirect back to mail app.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821934/launch-apple-mail-app-from-within-my-own-app

Comment: Thats not true. If I open a file from the mail application with whatsapp I can send this file to  a contact. After I send this file to a contact WhatsApp is closed and you see the mail I opended before(with the file) again. Not the email composer

Comment: Try out. If you find a way, kindly update as answer in your question.