# Back to previous app in Ionic 2

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have an Ionic 2 App, which may be started from browser using deeplinking. When app was started from a browser, I need a button in my app to go back to the browser and page which started my app.

I know that iOS supports "back to previous app" button (like described here: https://www.businessinsider.com/ios-9-back-to-previous-app-2015-7?IR=T) but how can I add it in Ionic 2/3?

Comment: You can't add that button; iOS shows it automatically when you move between apps

Comment: You might try [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29970918/ios-return-to-safari-from-native-app-without-opening-new-tab/30429912#30429912)