# Return to Safari from Native App without Opening New Tab - iOS - Safari

Tags: ios, web, browser, safari, tabs

My application is an e-commerce web app, for the payment I am using the third-party bank payment mobile application, so when the customer pays it opens the app, but when the payment completed and the user clicks on the back to the website, it opens a new web browser. which actually comes with a new session and the user has to login again. this problem is only in iOS mobiles with Safari browsers. for android it works.

Have you faced this problem before?

note: not a duplicate of this, because in this solution is for iOS mobile application.
[iOS - Return to Safari from Native App without Opening New Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29970918/ios-return-to-safari-from-native-app-without-opening-new-tab)

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

try filtering the callback you're receiving from the browser to control which view to present or handle such event.

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
let callBack = navigationAction.request.url?.absoluteString

}

Comment: you mean to add this function for 3rdparty payment mobile app?I do not have any control over the 3rd party mobile app.

Comment: You can receive the callback from the third paty payment in the delegate function I have said